# Creating files/folders recursively in python?

Tags: python, recursion, directory

I want to be able to write a script in python that will create a certain number of files/folders recursively to a certain location. So for example I want some sort of for loop that will create folder1, folder2, folder3 to a path C:\Temp. I assume a for loop is the best way to do this and using os also? Any help would be great!

Comment: for loop != recursion

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [makedirs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs). It may help.

Comment: Just make sure to catch exceptions from `makedirs`. It will raise one if it cannot create all the directories, for any reason... but also if the leaf directory **existed** before running it

Comment: in os.makedirs(path[, mode]) what does the mode mean? What is expected to go here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to create a folder recursively and then create a file in that folder.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

folder_path = Path(os.getcwd() + os.path.join('\my\folders')) #define folder structure
if not os.path.exists(path):   # create folders if not exists
    os.makedirs(path)

file_path = os.path.join(path, 'file.xlsx')  # add file to the folder path
f= open(file,"w+")                           # open in w+(write mode) or a+(append mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.4 you can use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to create a folder and all parent folders:

```py
from pathlib import Path

Path("my/path/to/create").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

If you want to raise an error on existent folder you can set `exist_ok` to `False`.